# mysql sum with format

Tags: mysql, sum, format

I want to rating my property to restrict the user to rate it only once.
So i am saving rating points and user id in the table.

Now i want the total avg rating of that property.

I am using my query like this

```
SELECT SUM(rating_number) as rating_number, FORMAT((SUM(total_points) / SUM(rating_number),1) as average_rating FROM post_rating WHERE post_id = 9781 AND status = 1
```

But i am getting errors. How can i get that total average rating.
Thanks

Comment: what error, div by 0 ? how about avg()

Comment: @Drew It is showing as syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT SUM(rating_number) as rating_number, 
FORMAT((SUM(total_points) / SUM(rating_number)),2) as average_rating
FROM post_rating WHERE post_id = 9781 AND status = 1
```